# payload.ipa could not be added to iTunes library because it's not a valid app

Tags: iphone

I have completed our apps, I want to test on device but when we drag and drop the .ipa file (file name payload.ipa) we got an error thus:

> payload.ipa could not be added to your iTunes library because it is not a valid apps

What is the problem? Our apps are working on simulator is fine. I am creating build on Xcode 4.

Comment: Can you tell..how did you create ipa

Comment: yes pallavi take the build and make new folder like name payload and copy the build into that folder and the compress it and change the extension from .zip to .ipa

Answer (score 0):

Check your payload folder name It should be Payload i.e case sensitive

Comment: thanks pallavi means we have to change the name payload.ipa to Payload.ipa